# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userServiceImpl'

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am integrating `hibernat`e and `spring` and `jsf`.

I got this exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userServiceImpl':
Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.sajjad.dao.UserDao com.sajjad.service.UserServiceImpl.userDao;
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.sajjad.dao.UserDao] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: orderDaoImpl,userDaoImpl.
```

Here is `userServiceImpl`:

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService<User, Integer>, Serializable {

@Autowired
private UserDao userDao;
//other methods
```

And this is `UserDaoImpl`:

```
@Component
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao<User, Integer>, Serializable {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
// other methods
```

And here is `orderDaoImple`:

```
@Component
public class OrderDaoImpl implements OrderDao<Order, Integer>, Serializable {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
private Session session;
// other methods
```

And here is `applicationContext.xml`:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!-- was: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> -->
<beans  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:flow="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms"
    xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:osgi="http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"

    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config/spring-webflow-config-2.0.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms-3.2.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.2.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi/spring-osgi-1.2.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
                      http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd">


<!-- Activates scanning of @Autowired -->
<context:annotation-config/>

<!-- Activates scanning of @Repository and @Service -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.sajjad.dao, com.sajjad.service, com.sajjad.user, com.sajjad.book"/>

<!-- Configure JDBC Connection-->
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
      destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/obs" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="2323" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
      p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
      p:annotatedClasses="com.sajjad.model.Book, com.sajjad.model.User,
         com.sajjad.model.Admin, com.sajjad.model.Order, com.sajjad.model.OrderItem "
      p:packagesToScan="com.sajjad.dao"
      p:hibernateProperties-ref="hibernateProperties"/>

<util:properties id="hibernateProperties">
    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">3</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size">50</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">10</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop> 
    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
</util:properties>

<bean id="transactionManager"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<!-- Detect @Transactional Annotation -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

**UPDATE**

`OrderDao.java`:

```
public interface OrderDao<T, id extends Serializable> {

public boolean persist(T entity);
public Session getSession();
public void update(T entity);
public T findById(id id);
public void delete(T entity);
public List<T> findAll();
public void deleteAll();
}
```

`UserDao.java`:

```
public interface UserDao<T, Id extends Serializable> {

public Session getSession();
public boolean persist(T entity);
public void update(T entity);
public T findById(Id id);
public void delete(T entity);
public List<T> findAll();
public void deleteAll();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Component("userDao")
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao<User, Integer>, Serializable {

}
```

And injecting dependency using qualifier

```
  @Service
    public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService<User, Integer>, Serializable {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userDao")
    private UserDao userDao;
   //other methods
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring says that it could not inject `userDao` because both `orderDaoImpl` and `userDaoImpl` beans implement `UserDao` - so it just can not decide which one should be injected.

Comment: No, as you see in the question, `orderDaoImpl` implements `OrderDao` and `userDaoImpl ` implements `UserDao `.

Comment: @user3808021 Ok, I see. Could you please also include the code of `OrderDao` interface?

Comment: Vladimir S., is correct as per the error. Try with @Qualifier annotation.